# I have to close VS code every time I import new module in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Every time I am importing some new module to my file, it doesn't see it. But when I close VS code and open it again it works. What can I do so I don't have to close it every time?

Comment: did you save the file after import?

Comment: cmd + shift + p then reload window?

Comment: What means "it doesn't see it"? Is intellisense not triggered, or does the terminal prompt `Modulenotfound`? Refine your questions to get better answers